# When are model objects created in MVC3 (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-relationship

Trying to understand when model objects are instantiated in MVC3:

I have a view for editing a "Person"; each person can have multiple addresses.  I'm displaying the addresses in a grid on the Person View.

This works great when displaying a person; I have a partial view which iterates through `Person.Addresses` and builds the table/grid.

The problem arises when creating a new person: the person object is null and the `Person.Addresses` reference is illegal.

I'm certain I'm missing something fairly fundamental here: since MVC will be (auto-magically) creating the new person instance upon "Save"; it would seem counter-production to try and create my own object instance, and if I did, it is unclear how I would connect it to the rest of the entry values on the form.

One last complications: the list of `Addresses` is optional; it is perfectly legal not to have an address at all.

As relational data is so common, there has to be a simpler solution for handling this.  All clarifications appreciated!

Comment: So you'renot actually _editing_ a Person, you're _creating_ one?

Comment: Correct.  When editing a person, the Model object already exists.  When creating a person, the model object is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the objects are re-constituted from the POST data in the form.  This is fairly basic, but MVC hides so much of what is happening that it is hard to see when you are trying to get your (MVC) bearings.

The sequence of items is:

1. Create form with all necessary fields; use hidden fields for non-displayed keys (ID).
2. User interacts with web page; then presses form submit button.
3. All field data is POSTed to the controller page.
4. MVC re-constitutes the data into class objects.
5. The controller page is invoked with the re-constituted class instance as a formal parameter.

Notes:

When creating the page: a form is generated with fields for each part of the object being represented.  MVC uses hidden fields for ID's and other non-displayed data as well as for validation rules.
It is worth noting that forms are created (typically) either by listing all object properties on the `_CreateOrEdit.cshtml` page:

```
// Edit.cshtml
@model Person

@Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
```

and

```
// _CreateOrEdit.cshtml
@model Person

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonID)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name, "First Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name, "Last Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.favorite_color, "Favorite Color")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.favorite_color)

//etcetera
```

or by using a template for the class (templates must have the same name as the class they represent and they are located in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder).

Using template pages is almost identical to the previous method:

```
// Edit.cshtml
@model Person

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and

```
// Shared\EditorTemplates\Person.cshtml
@model Person

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonID)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name, "First Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name, "Last Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.favorite_color, "Favorite Color")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.favorite_color)

//etcetera
```

Using the template method makes it easy to add lists (of object) to the form.  `Person.cshtml` becomes:

```
// Shared\EditorTemplates\Person.cshtml
@model Person

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonID)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name, "First Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_name, "Last Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_name)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.favorite_color, "Favorite Color")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.favorite_color)

@EditorFor( model => model.Addresses )

//etcetera
```

and

```
// Shared\EditorTemplates\Address.cshtml
@model Address
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressID)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.street, "Street")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.street)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.city, "City")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.city)

//etcetera
```

MVC will handle creating as many form entries as necessary for each address in the list.

The POST works exactly in reverse; a new instance of the model object is created, calling the default parameter-less constructor, and then MVC fills in each of the fields.  Lists are populating by reversing the serialization process of `@Html.EditorFor( model.List )`.  It is important to note that you must make certain your class creates a valid container for the list in the constructor otherwise MVC's list re-constitution will fail:

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Address> Addresses;

    public Person()
    {
        // You always need to create this List object
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    ...
}
```

That cover's it.  There is a lot going on behind the scenes, but it is all track-able.

Two important points if you are having trouble with this:

1. Make sure you have `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` for everything that needs to "survive" the trip back to the server.
2. Use Fiddler or HTTPLiveHeaders (Firefox plug-in) to examine the contents of the POST data.  This will let you validate what data is being sent back to re-constitute the new class instance.  I'm partial to Fiddler since you can use it with any browser (and it shows form data particularly well).

One last point:  there is a good article on dynamically adding / removing elements from a list with MVC: http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3  It's a good article to work through -- and yes, it does work with MVC3 and Razor.

Answer (score 0):

The addresses I'm assuming are in a table, not actual input elements and likely just <td>info</td>?
If so, then they won't get instantiated as there is no data being posted back to the server. 
You must have this data being created with elements that are posted back in order to have them mapped (by name) to their properties. The model binder will instantiate the objects and pass them to your controller upon postback if it can find appropriately named posted form (or querystring) elements.

Comment: So, would you attach the addresses table to the elements list so that it can be part of the POST data?  If so, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: @Robert The easiest way would to do something AJAXish, much like how the commenting system on SO works. When you click add comment, the comment is posted via AJAX and the div is updated with the new contents. You can do this with a partial view that is strongly typed.